# Linq query with GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a piece of code that performs a Linq query like the one below:

```
return uow.GetRepository<SomeProjection>().GroupBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y =>
                    y.Select(z => new EditableSomeProjection
                    {
                        Type = z.Type,
                        Key = z.Key,
                        Value = z.Value,
                        Component = z.ComponentCode,
                        Culture = z.CultureCode,
                        Code = z.Code.Key,
                        Version = z.Version,
                        Category = z.Category
                    }).ToList());
```

Basically this query works fine, but i'd need to adjust it so it gives me a slightly different result.

This is the scenario that i'm in. I have the following data:

```
ComponentCode    CultureCode    Key           Value           .....
MainLevel        fr             MainHall      (fr)Main hall
West_Level       en             MainHall      Entrance
MainLevel        en             MainHall      Main hall
```

Basically the Linq query gives me a `Dictionary` where the `Key` of the dictionary is the `Key` of the records (`MainHall` in this case) and the value is a `List` with those three records in it.

But i'd like to separate the `ComponentCodes` from it aswell. So the grouping by `Key` is fine (i guess), but i don't want to have the `MainLevel` and `West_Level` ComponentCodes to be grouped in the same list aswell. They should be placed in a separate list.

***Current Dictionary***

(Key of Dictionary == Key of database column)

```
Dictionary("MainHall", List(MainLevel        fr             MainHall      (fr)Main hall
                            West_Level       en             MainHall      Entrance
                            MainLevel        en             MainHall      Main hall ));
```

***What i need***

(Dictionary with 2 entries)

```
Dictionary("MainHall", List(West_Level       en             MainHall      Entrance ));

Dictionary("MainHall", List(MainLevel        fr             MainHall      (fr)Main hall
                            MainLevel        en             MainHall      Main hall ));
```

How can i adjust this Linq query to give me such a result?

Comment: The paragraph starting "But i'd like to separate the" does not make sense. What is "it"? What do you not want to have (included in the keys of the resulting dictionary or in the data)? Perhaps expanding you example data to show what you currently have and then what you want, *and* being consistent when you are talking about your names (ComponentCode etc.) vs. the data structure's names (eg. Key).

Comment: @Richard Clarified it a bit. Hope its better now.

Comment: do you try:  ** .GroupBy(x => new{x.Key,x.ComponentCode})**

Comment: From you example it seems two dictionaries to me, not one dictionary with separated entries...

Comment: What you need is a `Dictionary` with two element and they has the same  key?How is that possible?

Comment: It is clearer, but still needs work: under 'What I need' you appear to want a `Dictionary` with two entries with the same key (as @jarvanJiang notes): this is not possible. Also it is not completely clear why some values go into the first entry and some into the second? (Perhaps if you consistently labelled with field names?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group-by again the inner list :

```
return 
uow.GetRepository<SomeProjection>()
   .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
   .ToDictionary(g1 => g1.Key, 
                 g1 =>
                 g1.GroupBy(y => y.ComponentCode)
                   .ToDictionary(g2 => g2.Key,
                                 g2 =>
                                 g2.Select(z => new EditableSomeProjection
                                 {
                                    Type = z.Type,
                                    Key = z.Key,
                                    Value = z.Value,
                                    Component = z.ComponentCode,
                                    Culture = z.CultureCode,
                                    Code = z.Code.Key,
                                    Version = z.Version,
                                    Category = z.Category
                                 }).ToList()));
```

This code returns a dictionary of dictionaries i.e. :

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,List<EditableSomeProjection>>>
```

where the outer dictionary key is the `Key` property of `SomeProjection` and the inner key is the `ComponentCode`

Answer (score 0):

I think this works, however defining a class for the group key is a little complicated, but the code may looks clearer.

```
public class GroupKey : IEqualityComparer {
  public string ComponentCode {get;set;}
  public string Key {get;set;}
  bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(object x, object y)
  {
     GroupKey gkx = x as GroupKey;
     GroupKey gky = y as GroupKey;
     return (gkx == null || gky == null) ? false : gkx.ComponentCode == gky.ComponentCode && gkx.Key == gky.Key;
  }
  int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(object obj)
  {
     return obj == null ? 0 : obj.GetHashCode();
  }
}
//.....
//.....
return uow.GetRepository<SomeProjection>().GroupBy(x => new GroupKey{ComponentCode=x.ComponentCode, Key=x.Key}).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y =>
                y.Select(z => new EditableSomeProjection
                {
                    Type = z.Type,
                    Key = z.Key,
                    Value = z.Value,
                    Component = z.ComponentCode,
                    Culture = z.CultureCode,
                    Code = z.Code.Key,
                    Version = z.Version,
                    Category = z.Category
                }).ToList());
```

Comment: In order to use `GroupKey` class as key in `GroupBy`, you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods or provide a valid `IEqualityComparer`...

Comment: @digEmAll thanks, it's a little complicated that way. I'm going to remove this answer.

Comment: In relation to your question here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17944448/611288]. You **could** update your `.GroupBy` to use anonymous types as follows `.GroupBy(x => new {x.ComponentCode, x.Key})`. This would negate the need for your `IEqualityComparer`

Comment: @KingKing: actually the class you use in groupby (or in general as dictionary key) does not need to implement IEqualityComparer; there are 2 ways to make it work: 1) override object.GetHashCode and object.Equals of the class 2) create *another* class implementing IEqualityComparer and pass it to the 2nd overload of GroupBy. Otherwise you can use an anonymous object as NinjaNye said...