# Concatenate string in GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I'm doing a `GroupBy` with Linq on a `IQueryable`. But I'd like to do a `GroupBy` on a concatenated string. What I have now is this:

```
SomeList.GroupBy(x => x.Code + x.Location)
```

This works for me, however this also changed `x.Code` to the concatenated string `x.Code + x.Location`.

Is there a way to temporarily concatenate variables in a `GroupBy`, something like:

```
SomeList.GroupBy(x => (x.Code + x.Location) as TempVar)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want the group to actually look like. It would really help if you'd give us sample data and the expected output. Note that your assertion that the first version will change `x.Code` is simply untrue (unless your properties are *really* weird)... so you may wish to revisit that.

Comment: `x.Code` can be changed? that's a little strange to me, BTW how do you know it is changed? do you use it anywhere in your linq query?

Comment: Are you sure `x.Code` is changed and that you're not just looking at the `Key` property of the `Grouping` object? The key would be the concatenation of the two variables but that's doesn't mean your original objects have been modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by each property individually will result in the same as a concatenated grouping

```
SomeList.GroupBy(x => new {x.Code, x.Location});
```

Comment: I'm a little curious, how `GroupBy` is done without `new {x.Code, x.Location}` implementing `IEqualityComparer`?

Comment: It is because we are using an anonymous type. The `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods on an anonymous types are made up of the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` methods of *all* it's properties. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question

> Is there a way to temporarily concatenate variables in a `GroupBy`...

```
someList.GroupBy(x => new { TempConcat = x.Code + x.Location })
```

However I believe the answer by NinjaNye is better for what you want, rather than what you asked for `:)`.